# How to calculate one side of an arbitrary square

Tags: geometry

Firstly, sorry for my silly or simple question, and sorry for my bad English.
I have an arbitrary square which is like this:
[image: arbitrary square]
Maybe it can be solved with Pythagoras by splitting into two triangle
Can someone please explain me how to solve this problem?

---

Need to be verify:
[image: arbitrary square need verify]

Comment: and what is the angle between the 1cm side and the 64cm side? or is there 1 more condition? it seems like you forgot to mention something

Comment: Are the 0.5cm and 1cm sides parallel?

Comment: yes it is parallel,  @Mr.T i just want to ask, what happen if the angle is unknown? The angle between 1cm and 64 cm it is 90.8 degrees.

Comment: If the angle is unknown, you can rotate the 1cm side whatever you want (still satisfy the condition of the problem), therefore $x$ is not determined :)

Comment: @Mr.T Thank you for you explanation :) what if the angle is known like 90.8 (i have updated my image) how to solve it?

Comment: You must know maybe cosine theorem to solve this

$BC^2=AB^2+AC^2-2.AB.AC.cos(AB,AC)$

If you knew that, draw the diagonal line and just calculate all the agles and sides you can.

Comment: okay, thank you @Mr.T | Please check my answer image above especially at `90.35º`that make the 0.5 cm and 1 cm side is not parallel anymore, why is that happen?

Comment: It's just the error due to calculation. In the intermediate steps you may have results like 0.4242334... but you just take 0.42 to calculate in the next step, therefore it generates some variations. In fact mathematically both agles are equal to something near 90.35(or 90.36). is that help?

Comment: @Mr.T no, i'm just formatting it in the image as two digit precision. The real number that i used to calculate is `89.20390793351878º`, `64.776252593061 cm` and so on | the angle result is `90.353836968496º` and i'm using this formula `(A)=acos((c^2+b^2-a^2)/(2bc))`

Comment: I' sure that maths will work :))
You may also check the 0.44 angle.
If you calculate with such precision in EVERY step, you absolutely get such precision for the equality between 2 angles.

Comment: @Mr.T Okay i have correctly calculate it on the left side is `90.3577450893435` and on the right side is `90.35383696849602`. Thank you for the correction. You are right, it is equal. I think the problem is in our eyes and brain that creates optical illusion or different perception or something when seeing that images :/ am I right?